# Texmaker started speaking Farsi

Tags: texmaker, languages

I have a problem—suddenly the Texmaker user interface is all Persian. I have no clue how I activated this. So I need a way to switch back to English. This is on Linux. Perhaps I can edit a preferences file somewhere?

Comment: The `texmaker.ini` file can be found in `$HOME/.config/xm1` but I am not sure, that there is an language setting at all (apart from the babel setup)

Comment: It is inside `texmakerapp.ini` Use `Language=en` there, in the `[General]` section. The storage place is `$HOME/.config/xm1` (in normal cases) too.

Comment: @EmitTaste So I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: Why? It was funny anyway ;-)

Comment: @EmitTaste: You could have kept your answer (perhaps without that one word in it ;-)) as a self-answer in order to 'close' this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @christian-hupfer, I found `~/.config/xm1/texmakerapp.ini`. Somehow I had an entry `Language=fa` in there, switched back to `en`.